# How many permutations of $n$ elements start with the first element? or any of the $n$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

There are $n$ elements.  The number of permutations of these elements is $n!$. How many permutations start with first element? or any of the $n$ elements?

Comment: The title could really use some work

Answer (score 3):

If we fix the element in the first position of the permutation, the rest $n-1$ elements can be arranged arbitrary, so the answer is $(n-1)!$ and, as you have correctly noticed, it's independent of the element we fix in the first position.